# Why can't I use a method in a lambda?

Tags: java, android, lambda, rx-java2

Code:

```
source.subscribe(
                string -> {
                    if( observed ) destination.onNext( reverse( string ) );
                }
        );



    private String reverse( String forward ) {
        return new StringBuilder( forward ).reverse().toString();
    }
```

`source` is declared `ObservableSource<String>`.

`destination` is `Observer<String>`.

Android Studio underlines `string` in the call to `reverse` and tells me "`reverse(java.lang.String)` in `StringReverser` (my enclosing class) cannot be applied to `(<lambda parameter>)`".

I don't get it. `source` is delivering Strings, `destination` consumes Strings. and the `reverse` method takes a String parameter. What's the problem?

Comment: You should change `reverse(String)` method to static method.

Comment: You're right. Did that. Didn't change error message.

Comment: [`ObservableSource.subscribe()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/ObservableSource.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.Observer-) takes an `Observer<? super T> observer` as it's argument. The [`Observer`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observer.html) interface is **not** a *functional* interface, so you cannot pass a lambda.

Comment: You mean it's not like `.subscribe()` in RxJava 1, where you can use your choice of 1, 2, or 3 lambdas? Could I use 3 lambdas? (I guess the answer is no, as I see now that there are 4 methods to implement in `Observer`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andreas pointed out in the comments, I was treating an RxJava 2 `Observer` like an old-style RxJava 1 `Subscriber`. Doesn't work! Once I implemented all 4 `Observer` methods (`onSubscribe(), onNext(), onError() and onComplete()`) the error went away.